# Android URL scheme doesn't work

Tags: android

This is my code. I have read other's post about this issue. They said their code worked very well.
And my code almost the same as theirs. Why doesn't it work in my test. my device is Samsung I9300.

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.haibin.androidtest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="haibintest"/>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

ps: I using "adb -d shell am start -d haibintest:// -a android.intent.action.VIEW" on command line and it launch susccessfully, while use the url in the brower does't work.

ps2: I test it in opera and it work very well , so i know it will not work in some browers and devices.

Answer (score 1):

To use url scheme inside adb you can use the following command line:

```
adb shell 'am start "intent:#Intent;scheme=yourscheme://yoururl?param1=value1;end"'
```

Or you can even do it with QrCodes:
Go to [ZXing](https://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) and generate a url of this format:

```
yourscheme://yoururl?param1=value1
```

Then scan it with a QrCode app like [BarcodeScanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android)